# MATLAB Dynamic plotting

Tags: matlab, zooming

I have written a simple class that creates two properties which have a time and value array. The class has methods that simply plot them. Also, there are methods to listen to zoom events on the plots and calculate the average of the plot based on the zoom limits. However, it currently only displays the average in a text edit box I have placed on the figure; what I'd really like is for it to plot the calculated average value dynamically. Below is my code:

```
classdef ZoomPlot < handle

properties

    PropX
    PropY

end

properties (SetObservable)
    MasterXAxis = [];
    NewAverage = '';
end

methods
    % -----------------------------------------------------------------
    function me = ZoomPlot(varargin)
        if nargin == 0

            t = 100:220;
            x1 = -(10*(t-130)).^2;
            x2 = -(10*(t-150)).^2;
            me.MasterXAxis = t;
            me.PropX = struct('Time',t,'Value',x1);
            me.PropY = struct('Time',t,'Value',x2);
        end
    end
    % -----------------------------------------------------------------
    function plotPropX(me)

        x = me.PropX;
        plot(x.Time,x.Value)

        h = zoom;
        set(h,'ActionPostCallback',@me.ZoomLims);

        me.attachListener;

    end
    % -----------------------------------------------------------------
    function plotPropY(me)

        y = me.PropY;
        figure;
        plot(y.Time,y.Value)

        h = zoom;
        set(h,'ActionPostCallback',@me.ZoomLims);

        me.attachListener;

    end
    % -----------------------------------------------------------------
    function ZoomLims(me,obj,evd)
        %
        xlims = get(evd.Axes,'XLim');
        me.MasterXAxis = get(evd.Axes,'XLim');
        ylims = get(evd.Axes,'Ylim');
        xdat = get(get(evd.Axes,'children'),'XData');
        ydat = get(get(evd.Axes,'children'),'YData');


        zoomed_x = xdat(find(xdat>=xlims(1)&xdat<=xlims(2)));
        zoomed_y = ydat(find(ydat>=ylims(1)&ydat<=ylims(2)));

        temp_mean = mean(zoomed_y);

        me.NewAverage = temp_mean;            
    end
    % -----------------------------------------------------------------
    function attachListener(me)

        addlistener(me,{'MasterXAxis','NewAverage'},'PostSet',@Material.propChange);            
    end
end
methods (Static)
    % -----------------------------------------------------------------
    function h = propChange(metaProp,eventData)
        % Callback for PostSet event
        % Inputs: meta.property object, event.PropertyEvent

        h = eventData.AffectedObject;
        h.MasterXAxis;
        h.NewAverage;
        MyBox = uicontrol('style','text','Units','normalized','Position', [0.3 0.06 0.1 0.025]);
        MyAverageTitle = uicontrol('style','text','Units','normalized','Position', [0.15 0.06 0.1 0.025]);
        set(MyBox,'String',num2str(h.NewAverage));
        set(MyAverageTitle,'String','Average dB');

        propName = metaProp.Name;
        disp(['The ',propName,' property has changed.'])
        disp(['The new values are: ',num2str(h.MasterXAxis)])
        disp(['Its default value is: ',num2str(metaProp.DefaultValue)])
    end
    % -----------------------------------------------------------------
end
```

end

Example usage:

```
zp = ZoomPlot()
zp.plotPropX
zp.plotPropY
```

Any other critiques are also welcome to best optimize the code/architecture. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could add an empty line for the regional average when you draw the plot and then update the associated data for it when the limits change - http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/refreshdata.html

Comment: where would I put the refreshdata command?

Comment: I haven't used it myself so I don't know if it'll do what you need (hence comment not answer), just have a play with it and see if it suits your purposes. As for where it goes... if you think about what the function does and what you want to achieve then that should become obvious : )